# How do I get how many times a product has been sold from X date to Y date?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2

I would like to simply display how many times a product has been sold from X date to Y date.

I'll manually enter the date as '2022-02-24' for example. I just need to echo that value on a .phtml page.

I've Googled around, and many of the answers to this question are very, very, out dated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, just have to pass the product_id or the sku which ever is suitable for you and it will return the counter times.

In my case I have load the product with id and then get the sku of the product.

```
    $id = ''; //Your product Id
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface */
    $sku = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id)->getSku();
    $counter = [];
    $startDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime('2020-12-1')); // start date
    $endDate = strtotime("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime('2020-11-1')); // end date
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory */
    $items = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect(['*'])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['from' => $startDate, 'to' => $endDate])
        ->getItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $products = $item->getAllItems();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            if ($product->getSku() == $sku) {
                $counter[] = $item->getEntityId();
            }
        }
    }
    echo "This Sku : " . $sku . "Is Sold " . count($counter) . 'Times.';
```

Ignore the use of ObjectManager, you can directly add dependency in the constructor.